# SQL double many-to-many relations with only two tables

Tags: sql, django, many-to-many

Having two tables, one of them is called **Tasks** and the other one **Relations** where every task in Tasks might have **0-to-many predecessor**s and similarly, **0-to-many successors** that relations among tasks are stored in the **Relations-table**.

So, if Task_1 is predecessor of Task_2 and Task_2 is predecessor of Task_3 then I would like to store the following records in the **Relation-table**:

| pk | predecessor | successor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

for instance, using Django's model definition:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    duration_int = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Relations(models.Model):
    predecessors = models.ManyToManyField(Tasks)
    successors = models.ManyToManyField(Tasks)
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. I believe, that it is because giving the definition for **successors** as another relation to Tasks what already does exist might be inappropriate; although I also believe that **Relation-table** shall cascade back to **Task-table** with both of the relation: with **predecessor** and with the **successors** too in order to ensure the integrity.

After modifying the model based on given instructions in comments and answers, migration is done, but somehow the "relations" cannot be stored.

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    duration_int = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    relations = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Tasks',
        through='Relations',
        through_fields=('predecessors', 'successors'),
        related_name='whatever',
    )

class Relations(models.Model):
    predecessors = models.ForeignKey(
        Tasks,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='predecessors_relations',
    )
    successors = models.ForeignKey(
        Tasks,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,    
        related_name='successors_relations',
    )
```

Using the shell provided by Django, "tasks"can be created and saved, but it is not the case with the "relations".

Using the Django example Example I believe that the "relation" is part of "tasks", for instance, having two "tasks" already available in the DB:

```
>>> from simo.models import Relations
>>> from simo.models import Tasks
>>> t1 = Tasks.objects.filter(id=1)
>>> t2 = Tasks.objects.filter(id=2)
>>> r1 = Relations()
```

But whatever solution I try to save the r1 "relation", it drops syntax error; even if it is tried to save as t1.relations(...) it is just not accepted.

Would you please help with some advice?

Comment: THis code is correct. Django know how make these models. What is your error ? Me, i have set successors and predecessors directly in Tasks. I am not sure what you have coded is exactly the behaviour you have described. Django create related tables for n-n relation, maybe you do not have this information ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: It says: "Reverse accessor 'Tasks.relations_set' for 'simo.Relations.predecessors' clashes with reverse accessor for 'simo.Relations.successors'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'simo.Relations.predecessors' or 'simo.Relations.successors'."

Comment: you just have to set a related_name in your ManyToManyField declaration ;)

Comment: Thanks; I tried to add 'related_name="id"' to both but it did not bring any good result. for that I tried to follow the instruction in [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/) so that :
'class Relations(models.Model):
    predecessors = models.ManyToManyField(Tasks, related_name='id')
    successors = models.ManyToManyField(Tasks, related_name='id')'

Comment: related_name is the name you want to used from Task to access to table relation. you can not use an existing feild in Task or another related_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modeling makes not much sense, you use two [**`ForeignKey`** fields <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) for the predecessor and the successor:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    duration_int = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    successors = models.ManyToManyField(
        Task,
        through='Relation',
        through_fields=('predecessor', 'sucessor'),
        related_name='predecessor',
    )


class Relation(models.Model):
    predecessor = models.ForeignKey(
        Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='successor_relations'
    )
    successor = models.ForeignKey(
        Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='successor_relations'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are relating two fields to the same model, add different related names on the ManyToManyField.

```
predecessors = models.ManyToManyField(Tasks, related_name='tasks_predecessors_set')
successors = models.ManyToManyField(Tasks)
```

> Recursive relationships using an intermediary model can’t determine the reverse accessors names, as they would be the same. You need to set a related_name to at least one of them. If you’d prefer Django not to create a backwards relation, set related_name to '+'.

[Django ManyToManyField arguments ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomany-arguments)

[Django related_name ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)